# Pandoc: Markdown to PDF, fit pages

Tags: pandoc

I am looking for a way to export a `.md` book to a `.pdf` where each page is constrained (`/newpage` to separate them) but can have different lengths. Hence I would need an "adapted" page filling where if there's little content it gets more spaced out and conversely.

Otherwise I obtain this kind of empty pages:

[image: Example of page with too little content, hence it is not filled right.]

Book template:

```markdown
% Book title
% Author 

\thispagestyle{empty}

\pagebreak  

\setcounter{page}{1}

...
{page content}
...

\newpage  

...
{page content}
...

...
```

Pandoc command:

```sh
pandoc -f markdown -t latex -o output.pdf --pdf-engine=lualatex  \
       --toc --include-in-header titlesec.tex -V papersize=A5    \
       -V geometry:top=1cm -V geometry:bottom=2cm -M lang=fr --wrap=preserve   \
       --verbose  \
       input.md
```

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: Sorry if it is not clear. Expected output is that all pages are filled as much as possible, meaning they cover all the available space. May it be through an adapted inter-line

Comment: I imagine that you'd get better answers to this over at [TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Good point. Let me try here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/596446/pandoc-markdown-to-pdf-fit-pages - will keep posted if I get an answer.